# Vuejs Laravel maatwebsite\excel

Tags: laravel, vue.js

сделал импорт бд в excel с помощью maatwebsite\excel, если перейти на страницу, то скачивает нормально.
Фронтэнд на vuejs, запросы через axios.
Пытался использовать разные библиотеки для сохранения файлов, но они выходят не читаемые, так как в ответе приходят каракули.
Подскажите пожалуйста как правильно это сделать, спасибо

Comment: как вариант в laravel web роутах добавить роут для скачивания и давать пользователю ссылку на этот роут.

Comment: было подобное решение, там разница в том, что вы хотели отдавать сразу поток на скачивание пользователю, но через json этого не получится, нужен прямой переход к исполняемому скрипту, вы же можете сначала сохранять файл на сервере а затем отдавать ссылку на него обратно, вставлять ее в iframe в скрытый блок и файл сам будет отправлен на скачивание